# PDF to image conversion with Fitz on Windows 10 64bit segmentation fault

Tags: pdf, go, segmentation-fault, windows-10, error-code

I am compiling the following program on OSX and Windows (VM)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    fitz "github.com/gen2brain/go-fitz"
)

func main() {
    doc, err := fitz.New("ML-XX-XX-XX.000_REV1.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("finished")
    defer doc.Close()
}
```

On OSX This runs absolutely fine, on Windows I get a segmentation fault, and the output message (in command prompt) of `exit status 3221225477`

Googling around this seems like a buffer overflow, but not completely sure how to debug/deal with it. I thought it was a path issue (e.g `C:\\Users\me\pdfs\ML-XX-XX-XX.000_REV1.pdf` but seems not as I copied the pdf right next to the code.

I'm using the library for PDF-PNG [here](https://github.com/gen2brain/go-fitz)

Comment: Why the down votes? Down votes suggest this is "too vague", badly described, etc etc. The library is broken on Windows. Someone else coming here would discover this and that may be useful...

Comment: Well if anyone looking for the answer here, I contacted the author and they have fixed it now. So downvoted but got the problem solved. Be nice to be told why it was downvoted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user of a 3rd party library you can't handle such a fault gracefully.  You also can't really investigate it easily without source code.  It may be a problem in their own code or it may be a fault in the underlying MuPDF library.

You could try ensuring you're using the latest release to see if the problem still occurs.

You should open a case with the software provider for them to investigate it.

Comment: contacted author and they fixed the issue. Thanks